# TypeScript: click event's .target property fails to be found in EventTarget object

Tags: typescript

In the code below, TypeScript seems to be inspecting what I believe is a base class `EventTarget` but it can not find the `target` property.

It was working in regular JS before I recently converted this project to TS, so clearly the `target` property must be there. The alternative is I'm typing this variable incorrectly.

Is that the case?

**Also tried**

Typing it as an `Event, MouseEvent, HTMLDivElement, HTMLAnchorElement`. None of these cleared the red lint (it did move to id for I think MouseEvent).

```
const findClickedTab = (tabArray: object[], event: EventTarget) => {
  const clickedTabArray = tabArray.filter(tabId => tabId === event.target.id); // property 'target' doesn't exist on EventTarget

 // irrelevant stuff removed
};

// caller of above function, which attaches to the event listener
const switchSection = event => {  
  const tabIdsArrayOfStrings = getTabIds();

  const clickedTabIdString = findClickedTab(tabIdsArrayOfStrings, event);

};

document.addEventListener('click', switchSection);
```

**Update 1**

Below is my tsconfig.json. I know it's at least partially incorrect because files/folders outside `./templates` are being included (for example `./semantic`, which is parallel / a hierchical sibling of `./templates`)

```
{
  "compilerOptions" : {
    "outDir" : "./compiledJs",
    "allowJs" : true,
    "module" : "commonjs",
    "target" : "es5",
    "sourceMap" : true
  },
  "include" : ["./templates/**/*"],
  "exclude" : [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

[image: project file tree]

**Update 2**

I have added `"lib" : ["dom"]` to my `tsconfig.json` and changed the typing from `EventTarget` to `Event`. `target` no longer lints red but `id` (one level down) does. The error ballon in Phpstorm 2019.2 notes that `id` is not a property of `EventTarget`.

Updated `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions" : {
    "outDir" : "./compiledJs",
    "allowJs" : true,
    "module" : "commonjs",
    "target" : "es5",
    "sourceMap" : true
  },
  "include" : ["./templates/**/*"],
  "exclude" : [
    "node_modules"
  ]
  , "lib" : ["dom"]
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `tsconfig.json` please? Ideally, also a full [mcve] that one could paste into 2-3 files locally to replicate the problem...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, I have done so. I am currently thinking through where/how to create a good minimal example of this that will also use the .tsconfig settings

Comment: `EventTarget` is not the correct type for the event handler. `Event` is.

Comment: @apokryfos Ok, I have changed the type to `Event`. The red lint shifts to the `id` property. I can confirm the compiled JS works however, so `id` must be there. Also I should note a balloon  references that `id` is not a property of `EventTarget` (not `Event`) which I'm not sure what to make of, combined with the shifting red lint

Comment: Here's the problem [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) can be things other than an HTMLElement, so may not have `id` . You probably need to explicitly cast it if you know for sure it will be an HTMLElement. (I think) there's also a generic version of `Event` to hint what the `currentTarget` is (because `target` may also be an element other than then one attached with the event)

Comment: @apokryfos - I think that's an answer, I suggest posting it as one.

Comment: Ok, I have tried typing it as an `HTMLElement`. It shifted the red lint back onto `target` (and off of `id`).

While waiting for other feedback I will do some digging on MDN to get to the bottom of this. This level of object typing is pushing the edge of my understanding of the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are attaching an event to the document. This means you're listening for clicks on any of the document elements which then bubble up to the document. This obviously means that the target (which is where the event originated from) can be anything, even the document itself[*citation needed*].

If you are strictly looking for an element of a specified id then you can just use a type guard.

```
const isElementWithId = (t: EventTarget) : t is Element => 
   (t as Element).id !== undefined;

const findClickedTab = (tabArray: string[], event: Event) => {
    if (event.target && isElementWithId(event.target)) {
        const target: Element = event.target;
     // in here we know that event.target is of type Element and elements do have an optional id property
     const clickedTabArray = tabArray.filter(tabId => tabId === target.id); 
  }

 // irrelevant stuff removed
};

// caller of above function, which attaches to the event listener
const switchSection = (event: Event) => {  
  const tabIdsArrayOfStrings = getTabIds();
  const clickedTabIdString = findClickedTab(tabIdsArrayOfStrings, event);

};

document.addEventListener('click', switchSection);
```

In addition your `tabArray` parameter needs to be `string[]` for it to be comparable with the `id` property.

Note: If you know that you are looking for a specific element type (e.g. an anchor) there's a better way to determine if the element is of that type:

```
export const isAnchor = (e: EventTarget) : e is HTMLAnchorElement =>
    (e as Element).tagName && (e as Element).tagName == 'A'
```

`tagName` [is the HTML-uppercased qualified name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) (in HTML 5)

Answer (score 1):

The compile time error was cleared by using `(variable as objectType)` syntax to assert the `target` property from an `EventTarget` to `HTMLAnchorElement` object:

```
const clickedTab: string[] = tabArray.filter(tabId => tabId === (event.target as HTMLAnchorElement).id);
```

I also had to log the value of `event.target.constructor.name` to find the proper object type (`HTMLAnchorElement`).